# How to use 'assert' command to limit an input to only take number of columns in a set of data?

Tags: python, numpy

I have written a function that can retrieve specific columns of data when given an input of the data and a variable called col_num but I need to write an assert command that does not let the input col_num exceed the number of columns in the data (For this I am assuming that I do not know the number of columns or there are too many to count).

My function is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter = ',', skiprows = 1)
def get_column(data, col_num):
    assert(len(data.shape) == 2
    assert type(col_num) is int
    #assert goes here
    return data[:, col_num]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: I have added an image of the code which the function must satisfy.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlpMw.png
The code satisfies the middle cell but causes an error with the bottom one.

Comment: `assert data.shape[1] >= col_num`?

Comment: "I do not know the number of columns or there are too many to count" - but you _do_ know the number of columns: `data.shape[1]`.

Comment: I am confused how you should check if you exceed the number of columns without knowing the number of columns. Would `assert col_num < data.shape[1]` work?

Comment: I have tried using the mentioned code and still no luck, I do not know why it is not working. I should add that the function must satisfy the 'checking' code, I have included an image attatchement.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use `assert` for runtime checking. It can be optimised away: raise an exception instead.

Secondly, as the comments point out, you *do* have the data:

```py
if data.shape[1] < col_num:
    raise ValueError(f"Supplied col num of {col_num} is greater than {data.shape[1]} columns")
```

**Edit:**

Your assertion is failing because you are not actually testing for a negative column number: you need to add a line doing so.  But I repeat what I said above: assert belongs I'm the test suite itself, or in development, but not in production code.  You have no guarantee it won't be optimised away.

Comment: Thank you for the help, please see the edited post to try and get what im going for.

Comment: @Bayle I've updated, but note that this is really a different question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve here, replacing IndexErrors with AssertionErrors. The assert will crash the program if the condition evaluates to `False`, but so would an uncaught `IndexError`. You're throwing away useful exception information, both the type and messages, only to raise a more general exception.

If you don't intend to do or log anything if an error occurs, just let the exception happen.
If you need to log it or do something, catch the `IndexError`. If you can't fully handle it in the function, catch it, do what you can, then re-raise the exception:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter = ',', skiprows = 1)
def get_column(data, col_num):
    try:
        return data[:, col_num]
    except IndexError as e:
        logging.exception(e)
        raise e
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, please see the edited post to try and get what im going for.

Comment: What I meant was that I didn't understand _why_ you wanted to use assertions instead of relying on IndexErrors thrown by numpy. I've updated my answer to clarify this. It was clear that you wanted to use assertions in the original formulation, but the functionality you're describing is already there and in a more suitable format. IndexErrors.